# How to "extend" EF data model in other assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have solution with structure like this:

```
Solution
'-Project1
  '-Model1.cs
  '-MainDataContext.cs
'-Project2
  '-Model1.cs
  '-MainDataContext.cs
```

- Project1 and Project2 are simple assemblies
- Project2 references Project 1
- Both Project1 and Project 2 uses Entity Framework Core 2.2
- Project2.Model1.cs is derived from from Project1.Model1.cs
- Project2.MainDataContext is derived from Project1.MainDataContext
- Both assebmlies will have their own migrations

My plan is to have 2 separate apps where first will be using *Project1* assembly and second *Project2* assembly. Most (like 98%) of the data-model and business logic will be the same and we can say that *Project1* is the "reference" one.

If I add some field specific for *Project2* into Poject2.Model1 class and call the **Add-Migration** on *Project2* assembly, the additional field is not detected and empty migration C# script is generated.

**EDIT:**

In Project1.MainDataContext I've declared:

```
public virtual DbSet<Model1> Model { get; set; }
```

In Project2.MainDataContext I've declared:

```
using Model1 = Project2.Model1;
...
public virtual DbSet<Model1> Model { get; set; }
```

At running **Add-Migration** I get `Every concrete entity type in the hierarchy needs to have a unique discriminator value.` error (which totally makes sense).

Is there possibility to extend Project1.Model1 with Project2.Model1 so there will be 2 separate migrations in both *Project1* and *Project2* but the table name in DB will be the same for both types?

Comment: Should work fine.  It’s typically preferred to put shared types in a third assembly referenced from the other two.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft for your advice on having those shared types in a third assembly. I've edited my original post to refine my situation. Maybe now it will be more clear how to make migration work.

Comment: That error shouldn’t occur unless you have two different subtypes in the same DbContext, which is not what you described.

Comment: Ok, so I ended up renaming Project2.Model1 into Project2.Model1_1 (still inheriting from Project1.Model1) and in Project2.MainDataContext changed to `public virtual DbSet<Model1_1> Model { get; set; }`. Now the Add-Migration generates changes made in Project2.Model1_1. Do you think that is the right approach or could be done better? @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, and the setup you initially described should work.